# Compare two columns cellA and cellB and notate findings on cellC?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three columns A, B and C.

Columns A and C have values that may or not be the same.

I will like to compare the two columns.

If data found on cellA is also on cellB, I will like to put a Y on cellC. If not, a No.

Comment: are you trying to compare row by row as in A1=B1 then C1 = "Y", or if A1 is anywhere in column B then C1 is "Y"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have cell C be a simple formula such as

```
=IF(A1=B1,"Yes","No")
```

This will test if The adjacent A and B cells are Equal and show the value "Yes" if they are, and "No" if they are not.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Yes, I want something this simple. So, I just paste it on C and that's it?

I added that formula on C on the start of cell values for A & B and dragged all the way down. Is that the correct approach?

Comment: Yes, it'll work by just pasting, remember to fill it down the rest of the column if you're analyzing a full range.

Comment: I need exact match. For instance, if A1 = 397 and B1 = 397, I want Yes. If A1 = 397 and B1 = 396 I want No

Comment: Then this is definitely the formula you're looking for.